# Graphics2D Interpolation not playing well with very small BufferedImages

Tags: java, graphics, interpolation

I'm making a small game in Java, and it uses a pixel-graphics style, with many sprites 16x16 or 32x32 pixels. However, when I rotate them, I do not want "jaggies" along the side, so I used the RenderingHint

```
RenderingHint.KEY_INTERPOLATION
RenderingHint.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR
```

Unfortunately, because many of the images used are very small (16x16, 32x32) the resulting image is completely unusable. Output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qKSk.jpg

As you can see, the small graphics are blurred. This is the intended effect for large images, but for small images, it is very bad.

One solution is to increase the resolution of all my graphics, while keeping the "blocky" effect. That would be a pain, so is there another way to tweak the interpolation?

Thank you guys so much.

Comment: You told us the key, but not the value. However, the combination of the rendering hint values for *antialiasing* and *interpolation* will affect the result, but it will *also* depend on other details (OS, graphics card + driver...). Additionally, for a 16x16 image, there is not much in between "blocky" and "blurred"... But if nobody tries an answer, maybe I'll make some experiments and compare the results.

Comment: @Marco13 The value is RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR. The 32x32 image is rendered on the screen at about 256 x 256. The question was if I could make the interpolation treat the tiny image as if it was the size it was onscreen.

Comment: Without increasing the resolution of your graphic files, couldn't you just scale them up a bit after loading, and rotate that instead? Scale them up with nearest neighbor to keep the blocks, then rotate with bilinear

Comment: What do you mean by "scale it up"? Is there a bufferedImage method to do so? Also, the interpolation would also be useful when zoomed out a lot with the small sprites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upscale your tiny images and use that instead:

```
BufferedImage tiny = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));
BufferedImage bigger = new BufferedImage(tiny.getWidth()*10, tiny.getHeight()*10, tiny.getType());
Graphics2D g = bigger.createGraphics();
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
g.drawImage(tiny, 0, 0, bigger.getWidth(), bigger.getHeight(), 0, 0, tiny.getWidth(), tiny.getHeight(), null);
```

Replace the 10 scaling factor by the smallest value that gives acceptable results.

Do the rest of your rendering with high quality interpolation.